# glVertexAttribPointer set to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl

so I have this class:

```
class BRENDERDLL_API Vertex
{
private:
    glm::vec3 pos;

public:
    Vertex(glm::vec3 pos);
    ~Vertex();
    void setPos(glm::vec3 pos);
    glm::vec3 getPos();
};
```

I would want to change:

```
glm::vec3 pos;
```

to:

```
glm::vec3* pos;
```

Then I need to change:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

To point somehow where I storage data. There is obviously no problem with first one case, but what to do with second version?
Can I even do that or should I copy data to some array before?

Comment: @AlexFarber: Actually before OpenGL-3 core (which made the use of VBOs mandatory) you could place vertex attribute array data perfectly fine in host program address space and pass a pointer to `glVertexAttribPointer`; anyway OP's code seems to be using VBOs, so that doesn't really matter.

Comment: What is your original motivation for wanting to use a pointer? Do you want to `new[]` / `delete[]` allocate it? If so, please, for the love of everything use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @datenwolf At this point it is really rather skeleton but yes, new and delete solves warnings when building DLL. So you are saying I should copy data in vector? I can leave it that way, but I want to solve any problem as early as possible.

Comment: Well, if you `new[]`/`delete[]` it, then you've to copy it as well. But the benefit of using a `std::vector` is that the better of the implementations implement implicit-sharing + CoW, which actually *avoids* copies, where those are not necessary. Also using a `std::vector` prevents memory leaks and memory management bugs (use after free, under allocation and such).

Comment: I can't say it answers my question, but it helps me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing this to `glm::vec3*` will not benefit you at all, especially in modern GL. What you need to do is create an array of instances of `Vertex`.

You have to store this stuff in a Vertex Buffer and that means it needs to be laid out "flatly" in memory (*e.g.* no pointer dereferencing). If you have a contiguous array of `Vertex`, then you can take the address of the first instance and use `glBufferData (...)` to upload it to GL-managed memory.

#### The following code illustrates this:

```
std::vector <Vertex> verts;
const size_t size = verts.size () * sizeof (Vertex);

// Generate, allocate and upload your array to an OpenGL Buffer Object
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers (1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, &verts [0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// This points to address **0** relative to the buffer currently bound to
// GL_ARRAY_BUFFER.
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Actually I have an array of Vertex. But every invididial one consists of glm::vec3. I whould what to have glm::vec3 as a pointer to data because othe way in DLL it genereates warnings and some people says it could cause troubles. Anyway "it isn't even my final form" so  I am not that concerned :)

Comment: @Pershing: Yes, but an array of this class in C++ will behave like an array of structs. So each `glm::vec3` is contiguous.